# Click event not firing in jQuery and Hello World not working in Jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jsfiddle

I've been working on a program to display sales scripts for call agents. When the user clicks on a link the specified script should display in a div.

It was working fine, then my click event stopped firing. I decided to try out jsfiddle to publish my code and get some help. I stripped it down to the essentials and it didn't work there either.

What is unusual is that when I tried to run the jsfiddle's Hello World demo the event didn't fire either even though I copied it verbatim. The really strange part is that the pre-built version of Hello World works fine.

**Hello World**

```
HTML

<div id='test'>Hello World!</div>

CSS

    #test {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #ffb;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #999;
    }

    Javascript
    $('test').addEvent('click', (function() {
        $('test').set('html', 'Goodbye World!')
        $('test').fade('out');
    }));
```

[Hello World Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oodaddy/pf6c8qrk/1/)

**TestEvent**

```
HTML
<div id="scriptList" class="links" style="width:400p;height:150px;overflow-y:scroll;padding:5px;float:left">    
<ul>
<li><a href="#"  class="links" id ="1" name="link1" data-linkID="1">First Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="links" id ="2" name="link2" data-linkID="2">Second Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="links" id ="3" name="link3" data-linkID="3">Third ink</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="scriptWindow" style="float:left; width:950px; height:200px; margin:20px;overflow-y:scroll">
            Here is where the text will appear
</div>  

Javascript

            $('a').click(function () {
                changeScript(scriptID);
                return false;
            });

            function changeScript(scriptID) {

                var scriptURL = "script"+scriptID+".html";
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                alert(scriptURL);
            }
```

[TestEvent Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oodaddy/ncfgnwv1/)

Comment: Well I didn't get any help from the community but after a couple of days of flailing around I got it fixed. I think it was a delegation problem. When I changed the event handler to this it worked.

Comment: 'code' $( "#scriptList" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  changeScript($(this).attr("id"));
 });

Comment: This is not working in JSFiddle because you didn't include jQuery there.